# How to draw Box UEFA champions league

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

[image]

My source

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{add reference/.style={insert path={%
            coordinate [pos=0,xshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth,yshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth] (#1 south west) 
            coordinate [pos=1,xshift=0.5\pgflinewidth,yshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]   (#1 north east)
            coordinate [pos=.5] (#1 center)(#1 south west |- #1 north east)
            coordinate (#1 north west)(#1 center     |- #1 north east)
            coordinate (#1 north)(#1 center |- #1 south west)
            coordinate (#1 south)(#1 south west -| #1 north east)
            coordinate (#1 south east)(#1 center     -| #1 south west)
            coordinate (#1 west)(#1 center     -| #1 north east)
            coordinate (#1 east)   
        }}
}  
\definecolor{azulF}{rgb}{.0,.0,.3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \fill[blue,rounded corners=3pt,opacity = 0.5] ([yshift=-5cm,xshift = 3cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-20cm,xshift = -3cm]current page.north east) [add reference=R1];
        %\node[pt=red]    at (R1 south west){};
        %\node[pt=orange] at (R1 north){a};
        %\node[pt=red]    at (R1 north west){};  
        %\node[pt=red]    at (R1 north east){};

        %\node[pt=black]  at (R1 center){};
        %\node[pt=orange] at (R1 west){};
        \node[trapezium,rounded corners=2pt,draw,left color=azulF!50!white,
        right color=azulF!100!white,inner xsep=2mm,inner ysep=2pt,text width=16cm,align = center,font=\bfseries\Huge,text = white] at (R1 south){Title};
        \node[circle, draw=black, fill=red]    at (R1 south east){Logo image}; 
        \node[circle, draw=black, fill=yellow]    at (R1 south west){Logo image};
        \node[rectangle,rounded corners=2pt,draw,left color=azulF!50!white,
        right color=azulF!100!white,inner xsep=2mm,inner ysep=2pt,text width=2cm,align = center,font=\bfseries\Huge,text = white] at ([yshift=1cm]R1 south){Link};
        %\node[pt=orange] at (R1 east){};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Generates

[image]

Comment: What's the question? I'm tempted to think this is a joke since nobody in their right mind would try to produce the first image in TikZ. But maybe you are interested in producing only certain abstracted features of that image. That would be much more reasonable but you'd have to say what they are as all the crystal balls have been sent in for their annual polish ;). What does this have to do with `pgfplots`?

Comment: no kidding, I want to achieve is just the design of the box, no background, only the picture style

Comment: Also, is is courteous, and sometimes legally required, to attribute code which you have appropriated from elsewhere. The name of the author and a link to the original is a fairly standard format. I say this, because I don't think you would be asking this question if you wrote that code ;). Lower level PGF stuff is fairly advanced for most people.

Comment: What about the box? You've got the basic box. What are you trying to add and what's the problem exactly? Do you want the light blue bit to be a different shape? If so, which shape? Do you want to draw lines in it? If so, which lines?

Comment: what I want is to give that style are original

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? What are you trying to add or change about the second picture? Obviously, you are doing things a bit differently e.g. you've got 2 logo points. Could you explain why you are using the `add reference` code and why you are creating the picture with `remember picture, overlay`? That suggests you are using this in a particular kind of context which might affect whether a strategy would work for you or not.